# Displaying multiple record on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display multiple records from single person in a table using PHP however the other records are outside the table and only one record is inside the table. It looks like this [(view me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMwxw.png).

Here is my code

```
$resultSet2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT class_subject, target_grade, current_grade , cl.classID FROM students AS stud INNER JOIN grade AS gr ON stud.studentID = gr.studentID INNER JOIN class cl ON gr.classID = cl.classID WHERE (cl.classID = '1' OR '2')   and surname = '$search' ");
```

AND

```
while($row = $resultSet2->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['class_subject'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['target_grade'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['current_grade'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

How can i put them inside the table like the first one?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the closing table tag outside the while loop `</table>` also close your while loop.

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = $resultSet2->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['class_subject'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['target_grade'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['current_grade'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```